# Get customer custom meta on order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I just want to ask how to display custom post meta that I created on customer order detail page on frontend.

Like for example I want to get the value of this meta receive_newsletter on success order detail page on Woocommerce.

Thanks,
JM

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
 $user_id = get_current_user_id(); 
 $key = 'receive_newsletter'; 
 $single = true; 
 $meta = get_user_meta( $user_id, $key, $single ); 
 echo $meta;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is depend on where you want to show on order detail page. 
For example this hook: do_action( 'woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table', $order );
You can use:

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table','wn_display_receive_newsletter');
function wn_display_receive_newsletter($order){
    $oder_id = $order->get_id();
    $receive_newsletter = get_post_meta('receive_newsletter',$oder_id,true);
    echo $receive_newsletter;
}
```

If you saved "receive_newsletter" meta to user, you can use this

```
add_action('woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table','wn_display_receive_newsletter');
function wn_display_receive_newsletter($order){
    $user_id= $order->get_user_id();
    $receive_newsletter = get_user_meta('receive_newsletter',$user_id,true);
    echo $receive_newsletter;
}
```